# Google play services keeps restarting upon clicking on invite links

Tags: android, ionic2, deep-linking, google-app-invites, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using [Firebase-Invites cordova plugin](http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/firebase-invites).

I'm able to use `FirebaseInvites` function and send invitations successfully. The links are generated with my associated domain, but when I click on them, Google Services keeps restarting and shows a spinning wheel, and nothing else happens.

The example link generated by `FirebaseInvites`:

> apnXX.app.goo.gl/i/IZsum

When I generate a dynamic link on Firebase console, the format is slightly different:

> apnXX.app.goo.gl/xxxxx

The link that I generate on Firebase console works correctly and opens the app. 
Any ideas as to what am I missing? I'm testing this on Android.